# How to make the page automatically scroll to a element inside a content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am new to javascript and jquery so I'm not sure where to start.

I am working on a project and it would be nice if the page can auto-scroll into a certain viewport after the user has been inactive for a few seconds.

This can be seen in https://www.nfrealmusic.com/#store when it auto scrolls to a specific section on load up and completes your scroll when you scroll down alittle bit more in between the "merch" and "music" section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  margin:500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to scroll to the top of the element with id="content".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Scroll</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
  Some text inside an element.
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
</script>
```

**https://codepen.io/Fullstack_developer/pen/bGGKNJX**

would like for it to scroll into view automatically without having to press a button!

can this be done with jquery or velocityjs?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You forgot to call function after declaration. Add `myFunction();` after closing function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  margin: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">

  <p>Click the button to scroll to the top of the element with id="content".</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Scroll</button>

  <div id="myDIV">
    <div id="content">
      Some text inside an element.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You call scroll automatically using this way:

```
window.onload = function(e){
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
```

With jQuery, you can use .animate() to scroll without pressing button as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#content").animate({ scrollTop: "300px" });
});
```

```js
window.onload = function(e){
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  margin:500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<body>

<p>After loading, it will automatically scroll to the top of the element with id="content".</p>


<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
  Some text inside an element.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dosent seem to be working for me can you try it with the HTML And css in code pen?

Comment: I have added the code snippet. You can check it now.